# Is it possible to customize the CalendarView widget to display events and customize the colour (Gradient colour)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, calendarview

I am currently developing an app and I am stuck in implementing the calendar part of the app. Now I am trying to achieve something similar to this:

I did not find any functions on the original Calendar View which would let me display event indicator under days, add gradient colour instead of solid etc.
I wanted to implement this design to my app:

[image]

I tried using Compact Calendar View by SundeepK however I did not manage to implement an event adapter to go with this calendar, I always received an error on passing context, as the custom calendar does not use context.

This code below I tried to implement the List view to be filled with the events in the month. So on month load or scroll, events would be loaded, passed to the adapter and the list view would be filled with new events. However, whatever I did I always got an error that I can't cast android.Context to the custom calendar Context.

CalendarActivity.java

```java
        compactCalendarView.setListener(new CompactCalendarView.CompactCalendarViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDayClick(Date dateClicked) {
                List<Event> bookingsFromMap = compactCalendarView.getEvents(dateClicked);
                EventListAdapter adapter = new EventListAdapter(context, bookingsFromMap);

                ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.calendar_event_list);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                Log.d(TAG, "inside onclick " + simple_date_format.format(dateClicked));
                if (bookingsFromMap != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, bookingsFromMap.toString());
                    mutableBookings.clear();
                    for (Event booking : bookingsFromMap) {
                        mutableBookings.add((String) booking.getData());
                        Log.d(TAG, "Events in this day found!");
                        }
                } else {
                    Log.println(Log.VERBOSE,TAG, "\n NO EVENTS FOUND \n");
                }
            }
```

EventListAdapter.java

```java
public class EventListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Event> {

    public EventListAdapter(Context context, List<Event> feeds) {
        super(context,0,feeds);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Event feed = getItem(position);
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_feed_item_row, parent, false);
        }

        TextView eventName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_list_dataText);
        TextView eventDay = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_list_dayTextView);
        TextView eventMonth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_list_monthTextView);

        SimpleDateFormat simple_month = new SimpleDateFormat("Mmm", Locale.US);
        SimpleDateFormat simple_day = new SimpleDateFormat("dd", Locale.US);
        eventName.setText((String) feed.getData());
        eventMonth.setText(simple_month.format(feed.getTimeInMillis()));
        eventDay.setText(simple_day.format(feed.getTimeInMillis()));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Now from the screenshots here:

Calendar background can only be solid when I wanted to have a gradient as a background, the same as the selected date is a solid colour.
[image]

The event list item looks like this(Trying to find a way to add the events dynamically by month):
[image]

The ideal version should look something like this:
[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To Do that in easy and fast way you just need to follow this git hub library which is much option to do your required functions.

### Link (https://github.com/mahimrocky/EventCalender)

Bottom side will create in Recyler view as wel by using Database

Answer (score 0):

I have found one project which create calendar based on your requirements by modify little bit

Use this : [Sample Project](https://github.com/jignesh13/googlecalendar)

Your First need is make gradient background for calendar only need to set res/fraglay.xml gradient drawable resource to root layout background

Your Second need is make selected date gradient background you do it by modify drawable/selectedback.xml file

Your third need is bottom recyclerview it already available in above project if you want to modify event name layout edit layout/view_item based on your requirements

In above project you can set event by init method of GooglecalenderView you can set whatever event you want if one date multiple event is available in that case also it work fine

Answer (score 0):

While Using CompactCalendarView You can Add Events to the calendar and on click you can get the events of the selected date You can Use this code to implement ..

```
Long miliseconds = GettingMiliSeconds(formatteddate);


  Event newevent = AddEvents(miliseconds, "" + "Text You wants to add in your event ");

                        calendarView.addEvent(newevent);



 public Event AddEvents(Long milliseconds,String Description)
    {
        Event  event  = new Event(Color.BLUE,milliseconds,""+Description);

        return  event;
    }

    public Long GettingMiliSeconds(String Date)
    {
        long timeInMilliseconds = 0;

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        try {

            Date mDate = sdf.parse(Date);
            timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();

        } catch (ParseException  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return  timeInMilliseconds;
    }
```